# Monitoring Sun ilom on nagios

Tags: linux

I need to monitor the events from Sun x4100 ilom in nagios (using SNMP). Can some one please guide me on the steps to complete this?

Comment: http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Hardware/Server-Hardware/Sun/check_ipmi-2Epl--2D-plugin-for-checking-SUN-hardware-via-IPMI--2F-ILOM/details

Answer (score 0):

Nagios is a non-SNMP monitoring software, but you can have a look at the `check_snmp` plugin.